# How to correctly send the request body?

Tags: http, go, request

I'm starting to work with fasthttp in Golang and I can't figure out how to send key:value format. In default net/http I did it via url.values. I would appreciate it if you could help me with some sample code!
[Image from Burp Suite (How it must look like)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5t7Q.png)

```
var client *fasthttp.Client

var headerContentTypeJson = []byte("application/json")

type loginData struct {
    login string
    pass  string
}

func main() {
    readTimeout, _ := time.ParseDuration("500ms")
    writeTimeout, _ := time.ParseDuration("500ms")
    maxIdleConnDuration, _ := time.ParseDuration("1h")

    client = &fasthttp.Client{
        ReadTimeout:                   readTimeout,
        WriteTimeout:                  writeTimeout,
        MaxIdleConnDuration:           maxIdleConnDuration,
        NoDefaultUserAgentHeader:      true, //
        DisableHeaderNamesNormalizing: true, //
        DisablePathNormalizing:        true,
        Dial: (&fasthttp.TCPDialer{
            Concurrency:      4096,
            DNSCacheDuration: time.Hour,
        }).Dial,
    }
    reqTimeout := time.Duration(100) * time.Millisecond

    reqData := &loginData{
        login: "login",
        pass:  "password",
    }

    reqDataByte, _ := json.Marshal(reqData)
    req := fasthttp.AcquireRequest()
    req.SetRequestURI("https://oskelly.ru/api/v2/account/rawauth")
    req.Header.SetMethod(fasthttp.MethodPost)
    req.Header.SetContentTypeBytes(headerContentTypeJson)
    req.SetBodyRaw(reqDataByte)
    resp := fasthttp.AcquireResponse()
    err := client.DoTimeout(req, resp, reqTimeout)
    fasthttp.ReleaseRequest(req)
    if err == nil {
        statusCode := resp.StatusCode()
        respBody := resp.Body()
        fmt.Printf("DEEBUG Response: %s\n", respBody)
        if statusCode == http.StatusOK {
            respData := &loginData{}
            err := json.Unmarshal(respBody, respData)
            if err == io.EOF || err == nil {
                fmt.Printf("DEBUG Parsed data Response %v\n")
            } else {
                fmt.Printf("ERR invalid HTTP response code: %d\n", statusCode)
            }
        }
        fasthttp.ReleaseResponse(resp)
    }}
```

enter image description here

Tried to figure out how to integrate url.values ​​into fasthttp

Answer (score 1):

For request Body parameters:

```
req.Header.SetContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8")
```

Form the request body in `key=val` string and not json. Can do a simple Stringer impl or `req.PostArgs().Add(key, val)`

```
req.PostArgs().Add("login", reqData.Login)
req.PostArgs().Add("pass", reqData.Pass)
```

Output request

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: ....
Content-Length: 25
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8

login=login&pass=password
```